# Error Code 1242: Subquery retuens more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, subquery

I'm working on an update statement but I keep getting this error. Anyone have any advice on how to fix it. I've tried looking at solutions from similar questions for the past hour but can't seem to get them to work. Here's my sql statemtent:

```
UPDATE T_SUBSCRIBERS 
SET FULLNAME=
(SELECT CONCAT (T_REGISTERED_FNAME, T_REGISTERED_LNAME) FROM T_REGISTERED WHERE 
T_REGISTERED_UID = T_SUBSCRIBERS.T_SUBSCRIBERS_UID);
```

Comment: Well, as the error message clearly states, your subquery returns more than 1 row. We cannot tell you which of those rows is the correct one to use, since we don't know your data.

Comment: Seems like you have several rows matching the condition. How to chose?

Comment: @Vipul, that `=` is an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: Analyse your output data from sub-query and find out which value should be updated to target table, or might be you are missing some other condition to add.

Answer (score 0):

** Update ur sql like this :**

```
 UPDATE T_SUBSCRIBERS 
SET FULLNAME=
(SELECT CONCAT (T_REGISTERED_FNAME, T_REGISTERED_LNAME) FROM T_REGISTERED WHERE 
T_REGISTERED_UID = T_SUBSCRIBERS.T_SUBSCRIBERS_UID AND ROWNUM = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have more more rows that match the conditions than you expect.

You can find the offending rows by doing:

```
select T_REGISTERED_UID, count(*)
from T_REGISTERED
group by T_REGISTERED_UID
having count(*) > 1;
```

If you just want a quick-and-dirty solution, use `limit`:

```
UPDATE T_SUBSCRIBERS s
    SET FULLNAME = (SELECT CONCAT(T_REGISTERED_FNAME, T_REGISTERED_LNAME) 
                    FROM T_REGISTERED r 
                    WHERE r.T_REGISTERED_UID = s.T_SUBSCRIBERS_UID
                    LIMIT 1
                   );
```

In general, though, it is best not repeat column values like this in different tables.  When you want the full name, just join to `T_REGISTERED`.  After all, what happens if the user updates their registration name?